# TensorflowLite Inference Time 0s?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to inference a tensorflow lite model and I noticed that the 'invoke' method seems to be taking 0 time which should be impossible. I have the relevant code below with the output I see. I cannot for the life of me figure out why 1/10 or so show a reasonable inference time while the other 9/10 show 0.

Note: I have tried this with 100 different input tensors, for a test file (below), I simply created a 700x100 "image" data input.

```
import os
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def load_model(model_path):
    return (tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path))

def init_tflite(interpreter):
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    
def predict_tflite(interpreter, x_test_):
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]
    # If required, quantize the input layer (from float to integer)
    input_scale, input_zero_point = input_details["quantization"]
    if (input_scale, input_zero_point) != (0.0, 0):
        x_test_ = x_test_ / input_scale + input_zero_point
        x_test_ = x_test_.astype(input_details["dtype"])
        
    # Invoke the interpreter
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details["index"], [x_test_[0]])
    
    t1 = time.time_ns()
    interpreter.invoke()
    t2 = time.time_ns()
    y_pred = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details["index"])[0]
        
    # If required, dequantized the output layer (from integer to float)
    output_scale, output_zero_point = output_details["quantization"]
    if (output_scale, output_zero_point) != (0.0, 0):
        y_pred = y_pred.astype(np.float32)
        y_pred = (y_pred - output_zero_point) * output_scale

    return y_pred, t2-t1

def inference_model(frame, model):
    nframe = cv2.resize(frame, (32,32))
    nframe = np.expand_dims(nframe, axis=2)
    image = np.expand_dims(nframe, axis=0)
    image  = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)
    pred, diff = predict_tflite(model, image)
    print("Inference Time {a} ns".format(a=diff))
    return np.argmax(pred) == 0


im = np.ones((700,100))
im = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
model = load_model('models/tflite_model_f16_no_opt.tflite')
init_tflite(model)
for i in range(0, 10):
    pred = inference_model(im, model)
```

And here is the output for the 10 iteration for loop:

```
PS C:\repos\image-based-cell-sorting\ibcs\cellsorter> python .\tflite_test.py
2022-09-28 14:30:34.605393: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-09-28 14:30:34.605835: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 447900 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
Inference Time 0 ns
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, it has nothing to do with TF lite. The issue is that the time library is not updating fast enough for how often I am calling it. I assumed I was using the _ns because it would provide ns precision but it would appear that this library cannot be used this way.

I was able to get the average time by just taking the time before and after the loop and dividing by n. However, the reason I was taking the time in the middle was because I wanted to know the inference time in real-time as pictures were being grabbed in my application. I will have to find another way.